# Initializing an instance variable as well as attributes and a scanner

Tags: java

I've been having difficulty putting this project together. The idea was to calculate the average grades of students in a classroom with instance variables and scanners. I understand the output and input portion of the assignment but I am struggling the coding below.

```
public class Averages extends Object 
{

// Put any attributes / instance variables here. */
private String name;
// create grade1, grade2, and your Scanner.

// Constructor 
public Classroom () 
{
  // initialize any attributes that need initial values here */
  // initialize your Scanner
  return;
}
```

Then once created I'm supposed to modify my original coding so that it uses instance variables rather than parameter variables. Here is what I originally had:

```
public double calcAverage (double a, double b) 
{
  return ((a + b) /2.0); 
}
```

Comment: your code does not make any sense: the constructor does not match the class name. "extends Object" is bot necessary, as well as return inside a constructor

Comment: How, specifically, are you struggling?  Is there something in particular you are having trouble with?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Averages extends Object 
{

    // Put any attributes / instance variables here. 

    private String name;

    // create grade1, grade2, and your Scanner.

    // Constructor must have the same name as the class

    public Averages() 
    {

    // initialize any attributes that need initial values here ` 

    // initialize your Scanner

    }
}
```

```
I simply corrected your constructor, the constructor name must match the classname
```

Comment: Explain your answer.